# I keep getting this Error returned when using the modelsummary() function

Tags: r

I've been trying to create a table with the modelsummary() function but just get the following error code: ***Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : object 'std.error' not found***, and don't really know what to do.

The data I've been using is from the Titanic package.

```
titanic <- titanic_train %>% 
  mutate(Pclass = as_factor(Pclass),
         Sex = as_factor(Sex)) %>% 
  as_tibble()

model_a <- glm(Survived ~ Age + Sex, 
               data = titanic, 
               family = "binomial"(link = "logit"))

model_a_mfx <- marginaleffects(model_a)
summary(model_a_mfx)
```

Up to this point it all works fine, but the following line is what I'm having trouble with and I don't have a clue about what could cause it.

```
modelsummary(model_a_mfx)
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: "I don't have a clue about what could cause it" - cause what? Are you seeing an error message? If so, please share what it is. It also helps to include all the relevant code - `modelsummary` is not a base R function, so you must have loaded some library that supplies it?

Comment: The error code I get is: Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : object 'std.error' not found, and the libraries/packages I loaded were: modelsummary, tidyverse and titanic.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest versions of `marginaleffects` and
`modelsummary`?

Here is a full replicable example of what you are trying to do. When I
run it using the latest libraries, the table comes up without any
issues.

I paste the details of my environment below – the output of
`sessionInfo()`. You might want to look at it to see if there are
differences that would allow us to replicate the problem or identify the
source.

```r
library(titanic)
library(tidyverse)
library(modelsummary)
library(marginaleffects)

titanic <- titanic_train %>% 
  mutate(Pclass = as_factor(Pclass),
         Sex = as_factor(Sex)) %>%
  as_tibble()

model_a <- glm(Survived ~ Age + Sex,
               data = titanic,
               family = "binomial"(link = "logit"))

model_a_mfx <- marginaleffects(model_a)
modelsummary(model_a_mfx)
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Age | -0.001 |
|  | (0.001) |
| Sex | 0.547 |
|  | (0.033) |
| Num.Obs. | 714 |
| AIC | 756.0 |
| BIC | 769.7 |
| Log.Lik. | -374.978 |
| F | 89.712 |
| RMSE | 1.03 |

```r
sessionInfo()
```

```
## R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
## 
## Matrix products: default
## BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
## LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0
## 
## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
##  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
##  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
##  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
##  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
## [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
## [7] base     
## 
## other attached packages:
##  [1] rmarkdown_2.11        marginaleffects_0.3.3
##  [3] modelsummary_0.9.6    forcats_0.5.1        
##  [5] stringr_1.4.0         dplyr_1.0.8          
##  [7] purrr_0.3.4           readr_2.1.2          
##  [9] tidyr_1.2.0           tibble_3.1.6         
## [11] ggplot2_3.3.5         tidyverse_1.3.1      
## [13] titanic_0.1.0         nvimcom_0.9-124      
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] Rcpp_1.0.8        svglite_2.1.0     lubridate_1.8.0  
##  [4] lattice_0.20-45   zoo_1.8-9         assertthat_0.2.1 
##  [7] digest_0.6.29     lmtest_0.9-39     utf8_1.2.2       
## [10] R6_2.5.1          cellranger_1.1.0  backports_1.4.1  
## [13] reprex_2.0.1      evaluate_0.15     highr_0.9        
## [16] httr_1.4.2        pillar_1.7.0      rlang_1.0.1      
## [19] readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.13   data.table_1.14.2
## [22] jquerylib_0.1.4   checkmate_2.1.0   webshot_0.5.2    
## [25] munsell_0.5.0     broom_0.7.12      compiler_4.1.2   
## [28] modelr_0.1.8      xfun_0.29         systemfonts_1.0.4
## [31] pkgconfig_2.0.3   htmltools_0.5.2   insight_0.16.0.1 
## [34] tidyselect_1.1.2  viridisLite_0.4.0 fansi_1.0.2      
## [37] crayon_1.5.0      tzdb_0.2.0        dbplyr_2.1.1     
## [40] withr_2.4.3       tables_0.9.6      grid_4.1.2       
## [43] jsonlite_1.8.0    gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_1.0.1  
## [46] DBI_1.1.2         magrittr_2.0.2    scales_1.1.1     
## [49] cli_3.2.0         stringi_1.7.6     fs_1.5.2         
## [52] bslib_0.3.1       xml2_1.3.3        ellipsis_0.3.2   
## [55] generics_0.1.2    vctrs_0.3.8       kableExtra_1.3.4 
## [58] tools_4.1.2       glue_1.6.2        hms_1.1.1        
## [61] yaml_2.3.5        fastmap_1.1.0     colorspace_2.0-3 
## [64] rvest_1.0.2       knitr_1.37        haven_2.4.3      
## [67] sass_0.4.0
```